# Add account to SQL Server in .net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any API SQL Server 2008 offers for .net application to create and grant access authorities? Thanks!

Comment: Are you targeting a particular .NET version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .Net specific API for SQL administration is SMO. See [Managing Users, Roles, and Logins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162144.aspx). To create a new login you call the [Login.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.login.create.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL has CREATE USER and other related commands which can be used to create user and/or to GRANT various privileges.  This can be invoked directly from ADO.

This works for SQL accounts,  if you are using the "integrated" security model, you'll need to add new accounts at the level of the OS / Active Directory.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! Would you like to provide some food for thought about the integrated security model? I'm going to add a existing LDAP account.

Comment: To create AD Account, you may look in to ADSI (Active Directory Service Interface) which is a COM interface.  You may also be able to do this without COM, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675773%28VS.85%29.aspx.